# Reactants used for manufacturing of mustard gas

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> A compound 'X' which is used in manufacture of mustard gas reacts with (ozone) $\ce{NH4Cl}$ to form 'Y' and elemental sulfur ($\ce{S}$). The compound 'Y' reacts with $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{Ag}$ in separate reactions to liberate 'M' and 'K'. The compound 'M' is heated with $\ce{Cu2O}$ to give product 'K'. The value of $\frac{M_K}{\text{Atomicity}_Y}$ is:

The answer given is $3.50$.

Mustard gas is $\ce{Cl-CH2-CH2-S-CH2-CH2-Cl}$ and I know that it can be produced by the reaction between $\ce{S2Cl2}$ or $\ce{SCl2}$ with ethene, however, none of the reactants satisfy the reactions given in the question. What could be the reactants?

Comment: I think the question statement is wrong, as N isn't present in any of the reactants. myPAT adv?

Comment: @Rahul Verma I am PCB student, but yes, one PCM student sent me this.

Comment: I think M is NH3, and so NH4Cl may be part of the next statement. Since NaOH and Ag with ammonium chloride gives a reaction that feels similar to tollen's test.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! A screenshot or picture of an exercise is not searchable. Please consider rewriting it, so that it can be of help for future visitors.

Comment: I think i got the answer, not sure (about one part) so i am not posting an answer. First reaction is S2Cl2 reacting with Ammonium chloride (Not sure of role of O3) to give S4N4 and then S4N4 reacts with Ag to give Ag2S and N2 and S4N4 reacts with OH- to give NH3. Ammonia then reacts with cupric oxide to give nitrogen. So K is dinitrogen and Y is S4N4 and so atomicity would be 8 and mass of K is 28. So answer is 3.5. please Correct if there is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @Ouch X reacts with ozone to form Y, sulfur and amm. Chloride. So, X must be a compound containing sulfur, nitrogen, hydrogen and chlorine atoms which seems to be impossible. The closest I could find is trithioazyl chloride, S3N3Cl3.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal Nice attempt. I would say the question is flawed. Something is not correct. Also bad denotion is used. K can also mean potassium.

Comment: @NilayGhosh they said 'K' is a product. so that is fine.. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9780470132401.ch26
If somebody has access to this, this was the closest i could find for the reaction to involve Ozone, but is behind a paywall.

Comment: @Ouch don't take it too seriously. There were formatting issues. and there were some issues with the question itself. So the downvotes were for the issues with the actual question more than yours.

Comment: @Safdar Faisal thanks, your comment makes sense. Don't hesitate to post it as an answer..

Comment: @Ouch I cannot tell you why some users have down-voted, I can only guess. The initial ones were probably due to the image in the question, that is for many of our users a trigger. Then often, if the exercise question is longer than the attempt of making sense of the question, it won't be well received. From the amount of comments here, I'd say you'll get quite a bit of help anyway.

Comment: @Martin - マーチン Thanks for the support. Your and Nilay Ghosh's link (your initiated discussion itself) helped me. I am sorry for my previous comment, I got a little bit frustrated in beginning, I will gradually learn about site working. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your understanding and engagement. I see your question is taking up some momentum now. I understand that it can be frustrating, especially for new users, when your question is down-voted. I am glad you have taken the time to improve your question and I am positive you'll get an answer. Good readability will always help a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given question, it is given that 'X' is a compound used in the production of Mustard Gas $\ce{(Cl-CH2CH2)2S}$. Therefore 'X' may be $\ce{S2Cl2}$ or $\ce{SCl2}$ since they react with ethene to give $\ce{(Cl-CH2CH2)2S}$.

Since it is given that X reacts with $\ce{NH4Cl}$, this shows that X is $\ce{S2Cl2}$, since

$\ce{6S2Cl2 + 4NH4Cl -> S4N4 + S8 + 16HCl}$

So, we get the compound Y is $\ce{S4N4}$

Now onto the next statement which says that 'Y' reacts with $\ce{NaOH}$ to release 'M' and reacts with $\ce{Ag}$ to release 'K'.

$\ce{S4N4 + 6OH- + 9H2O -> S2O3^2- + 2S3O6^2- +8NH3}$

$\ce{S4N4 + 8Ag -> 4Ag2S +2N2}$

Therefore, we get that 'M' and 'K' are $\ce{NH3}$ and $\ce{N2}$.The last statement states that 'M' reacts with $\ce{Cu2O}$ to give 'K'. Seeing this we confirm that 'M' is $\ce{NH3}$ and 'K' is $\ce{N2}$

$\ce{NH3 + CuO -> N2 + Cu + H2O}$

Therefore, since Mass of 'K' ($\ce{N2}$) is 28 amu and atomicity of 'Y' ($\ce{S4N4}$) is eight. And so the answer is $\frac{28}{8}$ = 3.5